# Cancelling NetworkImageView requests in Android Volley

Tags: android, networkimageview

I'd like to know the proper way to cancel in-execution NetworkImageView requests in Volley.

I have a fragment that populates a listview with some text (retrieved via JSON RPC calls using Volley too) and each list item has a NetworkImageView.

In my fragment's onPause() I have:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    VolleyRequestManager.getRequestQueue().cancelAll(this);
}
```

Each of the JSON requests for the text I set the tag to this correspondingly:

```
    mRequest = new JsonRpcRequest<Data>(Method.POST,
            jsonRpcRequestBody,
            Dataclass.class,
            createSuccessListener(),
            createErrorListener());
    mRequest.setTag(this);
    VolleyRequestManager.getRequestQueue().add(mRequest);
```

The question is; with my NetworkImageView's defined in my layout XML resource files they don't share the same tag as the JSON requests so I believe they won't be cancelled on my onPause() code firing a cancelAll(this). Is there a way to somehow cancel the corresponding NetworkImageViews? Or do I need to hack Volley's code to add a method to cancelAll requests disregarding the tag comparison?

Answer (score 6):

**NetworkImageView is auto-canceled on detach from view hierarchy.**

According to the Google IO presentation by Ficus Kirkpatrick (Google Play app engineer), `NetworkImageView` auto-cancels in-flight requests when detached from the view hierarchy.

@ 16:35 ish in the video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9rkwO9yBosRvkQBJd5utmR&feature=player_detailpage#t=999

If you need more control, I'm not sure how to set the `Tag` on a Volley `ImageLoader` but am researching this now (why I came across this question).  Will update my answer if I find something.  However, it seems the built in auto-cancel is the most appropriate place to cancel most image requests.

Comment: This is true. I missed this point too and added tags to NetworkImageViews and wasted quite some time on that. Only regular requests can be tagged and then manually canceled from onPause.